# program just stop and doesn't say any errors

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a random fruit or veggie to put in my main array. The programs just stops and doesn't tell me what is the error. I am sure that my problem is in the randompick function but it all seems okay to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

class BoxOfProduce
{
    private:

    string veggies[4];
    string fruits[4];
    string ary[4];

    public:

    void setItemAry();
    void randomPick();

    //constructor
    BoxOfProduce();

    void display();     
};

BoxOfProduce::BoxOfProduce()
{   
    srand(time(0));
}

void BoxOfProduce::setItemAry()
{
    int x;
    string item;
    string item2;

    for(x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter type of vegi: ";
        getline(cin,item);
        veggies[x]= item;   
    }

    for(x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter type of fruit: ";
        getline(cin,item2);
        fruits[x]= item2;       
    }    
}

void BoxOfProduce::randomPick()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int i= 0;

    while (i < 4)
        x = (1+(rand)()%2);

    //if x one then veggies array 
    if (x ==1)
    {
        y = (rand)()%4;
        ary[i]= veggies[y];
    }

    //if x = 2 then fruit array
    else
    {
        y = (rand)()%4;
        ary[i]=fruits[y];
    } 
    i++;
}

void BoxOfProduce::display()
{
    int x;

    for(x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        cout<<veggies[x]<<endl;
        cout<<fruits[x]<<endl;
        cout<<ary[x]<<endl;
    }       
} 

int main()
{
    BoxOfProduce fruits;

    fruits.setItemAry();
    fruits.randomPick();
    fruits.display();

    getchar();getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code looks like C++, am I right?

Comment: It is very hard for me to believe that the application did not give you an error, did you step through your code with the debugger?

Comment: `getline(cin,item);` It is waiting for an input from `cin`. Is that what you mean by "just stop"?

Comment: no everything is working fine until i added my random pick function

Answer (score 2):

In `randomPick()`

```
  while (i < 4)
        x = (1+(rand)()%2);
```

where `i` index alter? it is an infinite loop.

so place braces in `while{.....}`.

like

```
  while (i < 4)
  {
    x = (1+(rand)()%2);

    //if x one then veggies array 
    if (x ==1)
    {
        y = (rand)()%4;
        ary[i]= veggies[y];
    }
    //if x = 2 then fruit array
    else
    {
        y = (rand)()%4;
        ary[i]=fruits[y];
    } 
    i++;
  }
```

Also note when you require larger block of code inside loop then before writing it first start with `while(){........}`.Then write your code.

Comment: what do u mean, i dont understand

Comment: @user3728593 `while (i < 4) x = (1+(rand)()%2);` is an infinite loop.  If you place braces `{}` around a larger block of code following `while(i<4)`, you'll have a loop that updates `i` so has a chance of eventually completing.

Comment: @simonc yes loop will completed when `i=4`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you forgot to add `{` after `while (i < 4)` and the closing bracket `}` after instruction `i++;` in the function below, your while will execute infinity only the next instruction `x = (1+(rand)()%2);`. This instruction does not update `i` which is used to break the while condition.

In this case `i` will always remain 0 and the the condition `(i < 4)` will always be true and your program will not stop

```
void BoxOfProduce::randomPick()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int i= 0;

    while (i < 4)
        x = (1+(rand)()%2);

    //if x one then veggies array 
    if (x ==1)
    {
        y = (rand)()%4;
        ary[i]= veggies[y];
    }

    //if x = 2 then fruit array
    else
    {
        y = (rand)()%4;
        ary[i]=fruits[y];
    } 
    i++;
}
```